# IOS Interactive background color animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm currently using PoP (Facebook animation framework) to animate some properties in my UIViews. I wanted to achieve an interactive animation that based on completion percentage would change the background color of my views form color1 to color2.

The current structure is:

Shared Manager sends to all child views

> animateWithPercentage:

and each view has this method implemented.

I can't figure out tho how to use percentage with background color, any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have 3 percentage values for three color ? Or just one value

Comment: what do you mean? I have two UIColors, and the animation needs to transition from one to another with a percentage completion, that comes from an UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

You can set two different views in the background. Each one with a colour and create a method with an animation that would modify the transparency of that view getting the effect that you want. Then, put in the front the second view and repeat the process.